# Free or open source dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, open-source, translate

I'm working on a multi-lingual search engine. I need to map keywords in English to corresponding words in following languages:

- Bulgarian
- Catalan
- Chinese
- Crotian
- Czech
- Danish
- Dutch
- Finish
- French
- German
- Greek
- Hungarian
- Italian
- Japanese
- Korean
- Lithuanian
- Litvian
- Norwegian
- Polish
- Portuguese
- Romanian
- Russian
- Slovak
- Slovenian
- Spanish
- Swedish
- Thai
- Ukrainian
- Vietnamese

I already know about eudict and stardict. Could you recommend some other free or open source dictionaries which cover one or more of the above languages?

**EDIT**
The dictionaries will be used for translation, but not spell checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into [Hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/), the spell checker used in Firefox and OpenOffice.

For information about the dictionaries used in these products see here:

http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Dictionaries

http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/dictionary

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/browse/type:3

Comment: @Patrick, sorry I forgot to mention the dictionaries are used for translating English keywords. Anyway, thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In sourceforget.net there are lot of open source libraries. One such project is TransDict. See if http://sourceforge.net/projects/transdict/ fits your need.